# one of uiviewcontrollers can not be presented/segued after localization import

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, localization, segue, xcode7

I made localization import to my app to add a Russian language support. Now one of my viewcontrollers does not present on screen after I click button which triggers its segue. I added print() statements and confirmed that prepareforsegue method is firing. Also viewcontrollers' overriden awakefromnib() method is firing. But methods like viewdidload() or viewwillappear() do not. Strange thing is I created two schemes for running, one is for Russian language and the other one for english (the initial language), the Russian language frame works fine and I can see viewcontroller being presented with no issue, it is the english scheme which has got issues. The app just freezes without any debugging messages. Any suggestion on how to overcome this issue or at least getting some debugging messages are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in one of the translation of the viewcontroller text in the storyboard. Found by deleting text one by one and running in simulator.